# Mapping a field to specific source value when there are multiple sources

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Hey guys I'm having an issue right now. I have a mapper to map a request to response also a CC5Response to response. I'm doing it in one method. But the problem is the field order id is both in CC5Response and my request object. So, compiler says that Target property "orderId" must not be mapped more than once. However what I want to do is that I want the TransactionResponse orderId with the value coming from TransactionRequest. How can I do that without compilation error. Here is my code that you can imagine the situation:

```
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.response", target = "assecoResponse")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.procReturnCode", target = "resultCode")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.errMsg", target = "resultMessage")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.authCode", target = "authorization.authCode")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.hostRefNum", target = "authorization.hostReference")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.transId", target = "authorization.transId")
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.orderId", target = "orderId", ignore = true) // cc5Response'daki orderId'yi yok say
@Mapping(source = "request.orderId", target = "orderId") // request içindeki orderId'yi kullan
@Mapping(source = "request.requestReference", target = "requestReference")
@Mapping(source = "request.financialGroupId", target = "financialGroupId")
@Mapping(source = "request.pos", target = "pos")
@Mapping(source = "request.transaction", target = "transaction")
@Mapping(source = "request.campaignType", target = "campaignType")
@Mapping(source = "request.campaign", target = "campaign")
@Mapping(source = "request.sale", target = "sale")
@Mapping(source = "request.additionalParameters", target = "additionalParameters")
TransactionResponseDto toResponse(TransactionRequestDto request, CC5Response cc5Response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the solution. The problem was using @Mapping annotation for target: orderId twice. When I remove the line below, it is fixed!

```
@Mapping(source = "cc5Response.orderId", target = "orderId", ignore = true)
```